# express-ejs-layout using different layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Im using **express-ejs-layout** for my project. my project has routing. I want use different layout for different res queries. for example if query is: [www.example.test/a](http://www.example.test/a), use LayoutA.ejs, if query is: [www.example.test/b](http://www.example.test/b), use LayoutB.ejs. My index.js part code is:

```
...
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/app_server/views'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(ejsLayout);

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
require('./app_server/routes/routeManager')(app);
...
```

how can I?

Answer (score 8):

I've just solve problem myself. I'll write for friends who face to same problem.

```
app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
res.render('view', { layout: 'LayoutA' });
});
app.get('/b', function(req, res) {
  res.render('view', { layout: 'LayoutB' });
});
```

Comment: Having the same problem. What is the structure and position of your layout ejs files that allows you to use `LayoutA`?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do:

First, I set a default layout

```
// app.js
app.set('layout', 'layouts/front') // assuming it's inside the 'views' directory
```

Then, I use middlewares for separate Router instances:

```
// app.js
app.use('/admin', AdminRoutes);
```

In my `AdminRoutes.js`:

```
// AdminRoutes.js
const router = express.Router();

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    // changing layout for my admin panel
    req.app.set('layout', 'layouts/admin');
    next();
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('admin/index'); // will use admin layout
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('layout', 'layoutsA', 'layoutsB');

const router = require("express").Router();
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");

// user router
router.use(expressLayouts);

router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
res.render("user", {layout: "layoutsA"});
});



const router = require("express").Router();
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");

// post router
router.use(expressLayouts);

router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
res.render("user", {layout: "layoutsB"});
});
```

---